# Internal Drive FAT32 Partition

Tags: windows-10, usb, partitioning, cable, fat32

I have a question about making this work but I'm not sure if it's even possible. So I have a home business involving embroidery. And I use my garage as a shop space with my machine and PC that I use for designing. So my machine is Linux based and requires a USB drive formatted in FAT32 to transfer designs to its internal memory. I'm wondering if I can use a FAT32 partition from my PC with a dedicated USB connection. I have already created the partition and connected to the machine with a USB cable with no luck. I'm assuming since the machine isn't getting a direct connection to the FAT32 partition, that it can't read from the USB. Is it possible to have that partition accessed from the USB cable as the main drive? Or at least have the machine see it that way? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Make a computer act as a virtual USB device for other equipment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120368/108618). This is for Unix/Linux, but should give you some insight nevertheless.